How to load from a CSV any varchar2 value with Oracle SQLcl load?
When trying to load a CSV file that has line breaks in strings with SQLcl load, if fails. The solution seems to be to set a different row terminator. But then if any of the strings have the chosen row terminator, you're back at square one.
(Using SQLcl 24.2.)
Let's say I have this table:
create table foo
(
    id number
        not null
        primary key,
    text varchar2(100)
        null
);

... and this CSV:
"ID","TEXT"
1,"Line1.
Line2."

If I try to load it with the default settings...
load foo FOO_DATA_TABLE.csv

... I hit issues (which shouldn't happen, but that's another story...):
Load data into table RC_OPS_USER.FOO

csv
column_names on
delimiter ,
enclosures ""
double
encoding UTF8
row_limit off
row_terminator default
skip_rows 0
skip_after_names

#ERROR Insert failed for row  1
#ERROR --Line contains invalid enclosed character data or delimiter at position 9
#ERROR Row 1 data follows:
1,"Line1.
#ERROR Insert failed for row  2
#ERROR --Line contains invalid enclosed character data or delimiter at position 7
#ERROR Row 2 data follows:
"Line2.,
#INFO Number of rows processed: 2
#INFO Number of rows in error: 2
#INFO No rows committed
WARNING: Processed with errors

After googling, the only solution I found was to change the row terminator:
set loadformat csv term ||

And for this case it works. But if any of the string values from the CSV happen to include the chosen row terminator, the issue comes back.
So, is there any way what SQLcl load can be used to load any string values without issues?

if your csv includes multi-line strings the best answer i have it to save it as an excel file and use the old sqldeveloper to import it. I'll file a ticket to have this deficiency addressed in a future update

This was a bug on SQLcl , now it's fixed in the new Releases : 24.3
SQL> @createTable.sql 

Table FOO created.

SQL> desc FOO 

Name    Null?       Type             
_______ ___________ ________________ 
ID      NOT NULL    NUMBER           
TEXT                VARCHAR2(100)    
SQL> load foo foo.csv

csv
column_names on
delimiter ,
enclosures ""
double
encoding UTF8
row_limit off
row_terminator default
skip_rows 0
skip_after_names

Load data into table SYSTEM.FOO

#INFO Number of rows processed: 1
#INFO Number of rows in error: 0
#INFO Last row processed in final committed batch: 1
SUCCESS: Processed without errors
SQL> !cat foo.csv 
"ID","TEXT"
1,"Line1.
Line2."

